# CreateJS how to animate a rectangles width and height?

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs

So I am trying to animate a rectangles size with Createjs. I found there are two ways to create a rectangle. Either:

```
var rectangle = new createjs.Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
```

or

```
var rectangle = createjs.Shape();
rectangle.graphics.beginFill("000000").drawRect(x,y,w,h);
```

when I add it to the stage on the first call it doesn't add. However I seem to be able to access the rectangles height and width with rectangle.width and rectangle.height. However; on the second call I don't have this sort of control. What I would like to do is access these properties with a Tween.

```
createjs.Tween.get(rectangle).to({width:###, height:###}, timeinmilli);
```

The only thing that I've had some success with is rectangle.scaleX and rectangle.scaleY however this moves the rectangle across the screen accordingly and I do not want this. Anyone know of some easy solutions to access and rectangles height and width properties in order to animate with them?

Answer (score 1):

An EaselJS `Rectangle` is just geometry - defining an x, y, width, and height (and that's it!). It is used to define rectangular areas such as `sourceRect`, object bounds, etc.

The `Graphics.drawRect()` method is what you want (your second example).

In earlier versions of EaselJS, you need to redraw the shape with a new size, remembering to clear it first (and update the stage). In newer versions (0.7.0+) you can use command objects to modify graphics much easier:

```
// Store off a command (the "command" after any graphics operation)
var rectangleCommand = rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100).command;

// Modify it
rectangleCommand.w = 300;
```

- I threw a quick fiddle together: http://jsfiddle.net/215wj7aL/
- Here is another sample using Tween: http://jsfiddle.net/215wj7aL/1/

You can see the documentation for all the [commands](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#property_command) online, for example, here is the DrawRect command: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Rect.html -- check out all the commands in the side menu for a full list.

Answer (score 0):

The Rectangle class represents a geometric rectangle, with helper methods, not a Shape to draw.

You can either update your draw each tick, or you can use a retained draw command.

```
var rectCmd = myShape.graphics.beginFill("red").drawRect(0,0,100,100).command;
//.. later:
rectCmd.w = 200;
```

http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#property_command
http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Rect.html